# npm start and install are not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]
I tried to run npm install and npm start but both does not work. I reinstalled the nodejs but still the same. How to resolve it?

Comment: you need to have package.json in the folder from where you are running the command `npm install`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to install the dependencies of an existing project (which the context implies), you need to run the command `npm install` in the directory where the `package.json` file of the project is.

If you've created a new and empty project folder, you need to first run `npm init` to create a `package.json` file which is used to manage the dependencies of your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did according to your suggestions. then it brings detail name, version and etc but when   i try to run npm install , it returns "npm notice created a lookfile as package.look.json. ". but when i when I run "feathers generate app " in command prompt is not recogonizing

Comment: Are you trying to generate a `feathersjs` application? If yes, you probably haven't installed feathers globally to your machine yet: `npm install -g @feathersjs/cli`. 

When you've installed it globally, you can run the `feathers generate app` command and then `npm start` to start the app.

Comment: I installed the feathersJS but the problem it does not create  but it brings, an error saying "conflict package.jeson"  i tried  to overwrite but it fails

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're in the head directory? For example, if your project is in:
`$ Documents/Projects/JS-Projects/Work/Client-Management-App/`
Then that's the folder you need to be in: the `Client-Management-App/` directory, because that's where the `package.json` file and the `/node_modules/` folder will be created.

Also, have you run `npm init`? That might be another reason why.